# Writing a set in the form of intersection of two sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I need to write the following set in the form of intersection of two sets, each of which is the product of two Borel sets (in on dimension).
$\{(x,y)\ |\ x < y \ \wedge \ y < k\}$

In other words, I want to find A, B , C and D where

$\{(x,y)\ |\ x < y \ \wedge \ y < k\} = (A \times \ B) \ \cap \ (C \ \times \ D) $

where A, B, C and D are Borel sets on the real line (one dimension).

I can write the set in the form of intersection as
$ \{(x,y)\ |\ x < y \ \wedge \ y < k\} = \{(x,y)\ | \ x<y\}\ \cap \ \{(x,y)\ |\ y<k\} $

but I cannot manage to write the new sets (on the right) in the form of the product of two borel sets on the real line (one dimension real line)

Comment: Why would you imagine that this set _can_ be written that way?

Comment: because  I need to prove that this set is Borel set using smaller borel sets on the real line, so it cannot be written this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can't be done. It requires that $A\supset (-\infty,k)\subset C,$ otherwise for some $r<k$ we have $(r, (r+k)/2)\not \in A\times B$ or $(r,(r+k)/2)\not \in C\times D.$ Similarly, it requires that  $B\supset (-\infty,k)\subset D.$ But then $ (A\times B)\cap (C\times D)\supset (-\infty,k)\times (-\infty,k).$

However  $S=\{(x,y):k>y>x\}$ is the union of countably many "Borel rectangles", for example $S=\cup \{(-\infty,q)\times (q,k): k>q\in \Bbb Q\}.$   Or we can observe that $S$ is open in $\Bbb R^2,$ and $B=\{(a,b)\times (c,d): a,b,c,d\in \Bbb Q\}$ is a  countable base (basis)  for the topology on $\Bbb R^2$, so $S=\cup \{b\in B:b\subset S\}.$

Comment: Thank you for your answer,  one more thing to make sure that I understand your answer,  how can I define the Borel space  (for two dimensions ) using the one dimension Borel space?

Comment: and could you please clarify more on the union of countably many Borel rectangles, I didn't get this part

Comment: Since $\Bbb R$ has a countable base (basis) $B,$ any $\sigma$-algebra $S$ on $\Bbb R^2$ such that $S\supset \{ b_1\times b_2:b_1,b_2\in B\} $ will contain all the open subsets of $\Bbb R^2.$  Hence $ \{b_1\times b_2:b_1,b_2\in B\}$ generates the family of Borel sets of $\Bbb R^2.$

Comment: and for the union part, I didn't get how the set in the question can be written in the form of union of Borel rectangles

Comment: Qhat Imeant by a Borel rectangle is $C\times D$ where $C,D4 are Borel subsets of $\Bbb R.4.. Open subsets of $\Bbb R$ are Borel subsets of $\Bbb R,$ so  the product of $(-\infty,q)$ and the interval $(q,k)$ is a Borel rectangle.

Comment: Delete the 4's in my comment above. I ran out of editing time.

Comment: thank you for your reply and patience. 
so it is the union of many sets. but how many sets? and how can I find or determine the value of $q$?

Comment: (1). A union of countably many  sets. (Countable means "finite or countably infinite").  The set $\Bbb Q$ is countable...(2). I took the set of  ALL $q\in \Bbb Q\cap (-\infty,k)$  in my answer.